# How to fix a widget in a grid row and column while the user is dragging it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, grid, widget

I want a widget which is been dragged by the user to be fixed in a specific grid cell when the widget comes near it, is there any way to do it in tkinter? I managed to make the widget draggable by taking the mouse position of user as he drags the widget, but i dont know how to make it fix into a grid cell.

this is what i use currently to move widgets

```
def make_draggable(self):
        def drag_start(event):
            widget = self
            widget = event.widget
            self._drag_start_x = event.x
            self._drag_start_y = event.y

        def drag_motion(event):
            widget = self
            widget = event.widget
            x = self.winfo_x() - self._drag_start_x + event.x
            y = self.winfo_y() - self._drag_start_y + event.y
            self.place(x=x, y=y)
        self.bind("<Button-1>", drag_start)
        self.bind("<B1-Motion>", drag_motion)
```

for example, if the grid cell left top corner position is (x=10,y=10) I need the button to get fixed in the cell when its position is near that value (like 9,9 8,8 9,5 etc)

Comment: "fixed in a specific grid cell" is rather vague. Is it already in a grid cell? If not, how are you putting it on the screen? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @BryanOakley I have edited my question to be more clear now, pls check it and help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what I have understood from your question, I have tried the following

```py
from tkinter import *

class Drag:
    def __init__(self,widget):
        self.widget=widget
        self.widget.bind("<Button-1>", self.drag_start)
        self.widget.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.drag_motion)
        self.grid=(100,100)
        self.margin=(20,20)

    def drag_start(self,event):
        self._drag_start_x = event.x
        self._drag_start_y = event.y

    def drag_motion(self,event):
        x = self.widget.winfo_x() - self._drag_start_x + event.x
        y = self.widget.winfo_y() - self._drag_start_y + event.y
        if (
            x%self.grid[0] in range(self.margin[0]) and 
            y%self.grid[1] in range(self.margin[1])
        ):
            self.widget.place(x=x-x%self.grid[0],y=y-y%self.grid[1])
        else:
            self.widget.place(x=x, y=y)

root=Tk()
root.minsize(300,200)

label=Label(root,text='Drag Me',bg='yellow')
label.pack()

Drag(label)

root.mainloop()
```

This basically creates grid of "cells" of height and width `100` and it clips it to the cell if it is in `20` pixel range of the top left corner of the cell. This is basically done by taking the remainders of the current coordinates when divided by the cell's height/width using the modulo `%` operator and comparing if this lies in the desired range.

Comment: Thank you so much exactly what i was looking for!!!